# WinUI 3 Desktop Multiple Binds Crash

Tags: xaml, winui-3, .net-7.0

WinUI 3 Desktop .net 7 WindowsAppSDK 1.2.230313.1

I have a List that is bound to multiple comboboxes with seperate SelectedItem  binds. If I were to select either of the comboxes, it works fine, until I select the next ComboBox, it then crashes the application. Any explaination?

Also a side problem, within the list, I have the ComboBoxItem IsSelected=True, that is not being acknowledged or bound. How do I fixed that?

```cs
public List<ComboBoxItem> Countries
{
    get => Extensions.GetCountries();
}

public static List<ComboBoxItem> GetCountries() => new() {
    new() { Name= "AF", Content= "Afghanistan" },
    new() { Name= "AL", Content = "Albania" },
    new() { Name= "DZ", Content = "Algeria" },
    new() { Name= "AS", Content= "American Samoa" },
    new() { Name= "AD", Content= "Andorra" },
    new() { Name= "AO", Content= "Angola" },
    new() { Name= "AI", Content= "Anguilla" },
    new() { Name= "AQ", Content= "Antarctica" },
    new() { Name= "AG", Content= "Antigua and Barbuda" },
    new() { Name= "AR", Content= "Argentina" },
    new() { Name= "AM", Content= "Armenia" },
    new() { Name= "AW", Content= "Aruba" },
    new() { Name= "AU", Content= "Australia" }
};
```

```xml
<ComboBox
    Header="Country"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.Entity.Individual.Address.Country}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.Countries}" />
                
<ComboBox
    Header="Country"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.Entity.Company.Address.Country}" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.Countries}" />
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "crash". Might be a regular error, best is to share a reproducible sample code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: We would need code, images, etc. so that we can understand it better! Like, what kind of error you get.

Comment: It's the same component on the same page. The app automatically closes when selecting secondary of the combo boxes after selecting the primary combo boxes. It doesn't matter the order of selection.  Crash meaning the app closes.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem in a sample app but works as expected. You need to check your code and see if you can provide more related code.

Comment: How did you reproduce this code, @AndrewKeepCoding??

Comment: 2 ``ComboBoxes`` bound to a single ``List`` of items as ``ItemsSource``, but different ``SelectedItem``.

Comment: That's exactly how I have mine coded, @AndrewKeepCoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same UI instances (`ComboBoxItem`) in different parents (`ComboBox`). You also should try to keep **ViewModels** without UI elements.

Instead of `ComboBoxItems`, you can use a **Country** class:

```cs
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Code { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox
    Header="Country"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Countries}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Entity.Company.Address.Country}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Country">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: The actual ComboBoxItem list is in a general Helper class seperate from the ViewModel.  The Countries property is called the helper list from the ViewModel. Everything has been seperated accordingly.

Comment: This also did not solve my problem.

Comment: Did you drop ``ComboBoxItem``s and create a ``List`` of **Country** items?

Comment: This did solve my problem. Thank you @AndrewKeepCoding

personal opinion: I think it's stupid you can't model off a ComboBoxItem